# I am trying to display Image in grid view but i can't do that Only Image name is showing , please suggest me solution

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

1. This Is My Controller

   ```
   [HttpPost]
           public ActionResult Create([Bind] Employee emp, HttpPostedFileBase Photo)
           {
               try
               {
                   if (Photo.ContentLength > 0)
                   {
                       string _ImageName = Path.GetFileName(Photo.FileName);
                       string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + _ImageName), _ImageName);
                       Photo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(_path));

                       objemployee.AddEmployee(emp);
                       ViewBag.Message = "Image Uploaded Successfully!!";
                       return View();
                   }
                   else if (ModelState.IsValid)
                   {
                       objemployee.AddEmployee(emp);
                       return RedirectToAction("Index");
                   }
                   return View(emp);
               }
               catch
               {
                   objemployee.AddEmployee(emp);
                   //return Json(new { msg = "1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                   return View();
               }

           }
   ```
2. code for add data

   ```
   public void AddEmployee(Employee emp)
           {
               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
               {
                   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spaddEmployee", con);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", emp.FirstName);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", emp.LastName);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", emp.Gender);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(emp.DOB));
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", emp.Hobby);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", emp.Photo);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", emp.City);

                   con.Open();
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   con.Close();
               }
           }
   ```
3. following is my creat and Index view , data show on Index page

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
               
                       
                           @Html.TextBox("Photo", "", new { type = "file" }) 
                           

                       
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Comment: You haven't used any ```img``` tag to show your image

Comment: can not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store not only image name but also Path for the same image into database.

For more details refer a below URL with an example:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-inside-WebGrid-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: in this demo they use Entity Framework, but i want without EF Model

Comment: Refer to this URL:  http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/05/how-to-upload-image-to-database-and-show-in-view-without-image-handler.html[^]

Answer (score 0):

add FormMethod.post method in creat view